# static QStack top() getting me First-chance exception after minute running

Tags: c++, qt, exception

i can catch the exception from visual studio 2008 
where i run it in release mode with debug info enabled , with all exceptions Debug->Exceptions menu and
SEH Exceptions (/EHa) turned on in the IDE
i have :
QTimer that calling method :

```
m_NotificationTimer = new QTimer();
connect(m_NotificationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()),
            this,SLOT(CheckOuterLinks()/*,Qt::DirectConnection*/));
```

this function that bean called every 3 seconds:

```
void CollectorWorker2::CheckOuterLinks()
{


            while(!rpm_urlStack->isEmptyO())
            {

                        QMutexLocker locker(m_pMutex1);

                        std::map<std::string,std::string > m = rpm_urlStack->topO();

                        locker.unlock();
            }

}
```

the top0() method is function that get the top element from QStack , member function 
and it looks like this it removed the element with pop() somewhere else:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string >  UrlStack::topO()
{

    std::map<std::string,std::string > m;
    try
    {

        static QMutex mutex;
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
            m = m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack.top();


        return m;

    }

    catch (std::exception const & e)
    {
      std::cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;

    }
    catch (...)
    {
       std::cout << "Unknown exception." << std::endl;      
    }

}
```

the m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack is static member and gets filled with elements from somewhere else in the code protected with mutex also .
the m_OuterLinksToProcessOutStack filled with members it left something like 2000 elements 
i do check it somewhere else , so its not problem of empty stack .
the problem i have that after minute of running the application im getting this error in runtime:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00403fc2 in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

on the top() method of the QStack

Comment: Think about what happens if two threads arrive at exactly the same time and the stack contains exactly one element.

Comment: well i have the mutex that supose to protect it and each time i get the exception , i can see that the QStack have like 2000 more elements

Comment: If TA and TB arrive in CheckOuterLinks at the same time, with one item in stack, they'll both enter the body of while thinking "there's something on the stack". On of them (say TB) will block on the mutex - it's frozen in that state of mind "there's something there". What happens when TA releases the lock?

Comment: As i know tb will enter to do its job ,but again its not the case where last item on stack problem.it still contains like 2000 items